# EF - HasQueryFilter equivalent for insertion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a multi website app with same database and same schema for every website.
I use the following to isolate queries for every entity:

```
public partial class WebsiteContext : DbContext
{
  
      public WebsiteContext(int website_id)
        {
           this.website_id = website_id;
        }
             modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
                {
        
                    entity.HasQueryFilter(c=>c.WebsiteId == this.website_id)
                    // ...
               }
        
          modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
                {
        
                    entity.HasQueryFilter(p=>p.WebsiteId == this.website_id)
                    // ...
               }
              // other entities ...
}
```

But some methods like "Add" are not isolated .So when I call it it throws exception because WebsiteId  is needed.
How can I make sure all of my queries including insertions have default value for Website_id

Edit:
Everyone is talking about how to filter update/select.
Thanks to EF's HasQueryFilter it's done.
What I want is a safe DbCotentxt which is not able to add any object/row with WebsiteID other than website_id (the constructor argument)
I previously added this methods to the context:

```
  public void addComment(Comment comment){
        comment.WebsiteId = this.website_id;
        this.Comments.Add(comment);
    }

     public void addPost(Post post)
     {
        post.WebsiteId = this.website_id;
        this.Posts.Add(post);
     }

// the rest ...
```

So let me ask my question other way:

How can I make "Add" and other insertion methods disable or private/protected ?

@Panagiotis Kanavos

I know what I can do, I just want to have some isolation.
I want my context to be innocent so if I do something wrong he doesn't.

Comment: Why would you need that? If you don't want to add something, don't add it. Besides, `Add` doesn't add anything, it attaches an object in the `Added` state. It's `SaveChanges` that generates the INSERT statements.

Comment: Is your actual question how to set the TenantID automatically at the ORM layer instead of the application layer?

Comment: [Multi-tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy)

Comment: You would do this via other methods, such as passing the website_id as a header (or buried in the security token), decode it during middleware, and then use it in your repository layer.  Then the application layer never even knows it's there.

Comment: @neil thank you, but how I get website_id is not my problem . how I modify insertions correctly is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an accessor to capture the website_id during middleware, and then in your repository, use it to insert into the domains.

```
public interface IWebSiteIdAccessor
{
     string WebsiteId {get;set;}
}


// Middleware
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IWebSiteIdAccessor accessor)
{
    // Get the website id from a header or similar
    accessor.WebsiteId = context.Headers["X-WebsiteId"].ToString();
}


// Repository
class MyRepository
{
    private readonly IWebsiteIdAccessor accessor;

    public MyRepository(IWebsiteIdAccessor accessor)
       => this.accessor = accessor;

    public void addComment(Comment comment){
        comment.WebsiteId = this.accessor.WebsiteId;
        this.Comments.Add(comment);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank You , But it seems you didn't even read my comment

Comment: "how I modify insertions correctly is." ?  That's the responsibility of MyRespository.

Comment: Maybe your issue is that you are passing entity objects to your repository, which is incorrect.  The application should call the repository with a DTO (without a website_id property), and the repository converts that to an entity (which DOES have a website_id).